# How to choose the oputput directory with getstatusoutput

Tags: python, directory, command, output

i am a beginner in programming.
I have to run a program in python and save the output in a concrete folder, but all the output is saved in my home, could anyone tell me how to choose the directory?

i used this command:

**commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)**

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.. It would help in answering !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know how to choose **WHERE** you can write a file to. Let's say you have the output you want already saved in a variable:

```
my_output_text = "Some interesting text"
```

Typically, you should write the output to a place that your program has write-access to. Because you have full write-access to your home directory, that's probably why it is currently pointing there. You can also use a temp directory like `/tmp/` on most *nix based systems. Simply create a variable to that file like this:

```
my_preferred_output_file = '/tmp/my_output.txt'  # this can be anywhere your program has write-access to
```

Then write code that saves to it. One quick way is you use a `with` context manager:

```
with open(my_preferred_output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(my_output_text)
```

Another method is to use logging.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filemode='w', filename=my_preferred_output_file, level=logging.INFO)

log = logging.getLogger('output_log')  # this just names your logger
log.info(my_output_text)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html for more info.